# When is the set of faces of a convex polytope algebraically independent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

*This is related to [another question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/315796/36720)*

Let $V=\Bbb R^n$. Morelli defined the (commutative unital) ring $L(V)$ to be the additive group generated by the indicator functions of convex polytopes in $V$ with multiplication induced by Minkowski sum.

**Question:** Are there any positive-dimensional polytopes $P$ satisfy the following condition (*)? If there are, is there a “good” (take that to mean what you will) characterization of them?

> (*) Viewed as elements of $L(V)$, the set of faces of $P$ (including $P$ itself) is algebraically independent (over $\Bbb Z$).

**Example:** (*) is always false for zonotopes essentially by definition.

Comment: what is the addition operation in the ring $L(V)$?

Comment: @YossiLonke Minkowski sum

Comment: You write that "multiplication is induced by Minkowski sum." In a ring, there are two operations: multiplication and addition. So I repeat my question: what is the addition operation in this ring?

Comment: @YossiLonke The multiplication operation is minkowski sum, while the addition operation is function addition